# simple jquery div swap with anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, toggle, fadeout

I have 4 links, and 4 content boxes which the first content box is visible and the other 3 are hidden.  I believe I need to use javascript to toggle these content boxes.  When I click the second link it should show the second content box and hide the first one.  if it was possible to fade in and out that would be awesome.  Please help I have been searching for a tutorial doing exactly this and I just cant put it together

Comment: made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/svr2k/

Comment: Have a look at Bootstrap's tabs, I think they are what you are looking for: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 0):

According to your current structure, I changed the HTML code and come up with this jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("div").fadeOut("slow")
    $("#"+$(this).text()).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svr2k/2/)..